# c# unmanaged PInvoke AccessViolation

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, intptr

I have C++ DLL.
When call method from this DLL in C# AccessViolation was been throwing.
What in my code is wrong? Can someone help me?
C++ Header part:

```
typedef PVOID X_HANDLE;
XREADER_API BOOL ReaderOpen(X_HANDLE *pxHandle);
XREADER_API BOOL ReaderReceiveW26(X_HANDLE xHandle, LPVOID pBuffer, DWORD nBufferSize);
```

Working Example part C++:

```
X_HANDLE hReader;
unsigned char xKeyBuffer[3];
ReaderOpen(&hReader);
ReaderReceiveW26(hReader,xKeyBuffer,sizeof(xKeyBuffer));
```

My C# Code:

```
[DllImport("reader.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool ReaderOpen(IntPtr reference);
[DllImport("reader.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool ReaderReceiveW26(IntPtr hReader, IntPtr pBuffer, uint xKeyBuffer);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] received = new byte[3];
        IntPtr unmanagedPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(received.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(received, 0, unmanagedPointer, received.Length);
        IntPtr hReader = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(uint));
        var qqq = uint.Parse((Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(byte)) * received.Length).ToString());
        ReaderOpen(hReader);
        while (true)
        {
            if (ReaderReceiveW26(hReader, unmanagedPointer, qqq))

            {
                Console.WriteLine("!");
            }
        }
    }
```

AccessViolation throwing at ReaderReceiveW26(hReader, unmanagedPointer, qqq)

Thanks for your patience!

Comment: The first argument you pass is nonsense, you are supposed to call ReaderOpen() first and use the returned IntPtr.  Its declaration is wrong, the argument is `out IntPtr`.  The second argument of ReaderReceiveW26() ought to be `byte[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Hast Passant comment!
If we want use IntPtr or smth which edited by unmanaged code we need use

```
out paramName
```

For PVOID we can pass real c# type.

Working example:

```
[DllImport("reader.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool ReaderOpen(out IntPtr reference);
[DllImport("reader.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool ReaderReceiveW26(IntPtr hReader, byte[] pBuffer, uint xKeyBuffer);
```